# C# program seems to be modifying a parameter marked as readonly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, encryption, pass-by-reference

I have a function named [ARCMF](https://github.com/Naquino14/ARC-128/blob/6ac1656716fdc90b19e7507c7a030010c977770d/ARC-128/ARC128.cs#L264) that is supposed to return the same pseudorandom output for every same set of inputs `state` and `keys` which are both passed by readonly reference using the keyword `in`. However, when I try running this function twice, the first and second result are never equal to each other (but are equal every time I restart the program). After extensive debugging, it seems as though the variable in question gets modified. I tried setting it to readonly but it STILL gets modified somehow. This has left me stumped for hours...

[All of my code is here on this repo.](https://github.com/Naquino14/ARC-128/blob/master/ARC-128)

[This is the variable in question](https://github.com/Naquino14/ARC-128/blob/6ac1656716fdc90b19e7507c7a030010c977770d/ARC-128/Program.cs#L14) (from now on I will refer to as IV) which I have in a watch window during debugging, and I pass it  [into a function called ARCMF...](https://github.com/Naquino14/ARC-128/blob/6ac1656716fdc90b19e7507c7a030010c977770d/ARC-128/ARC128.cs#L264)

```
var arc = new ARC128(key, iv);
var mf0 = arc.ARCMF(iv, arc.Schedule(key, iv, 1));
arc.PrintArray(mf0, "Main Function Iteration 0 Results");
var mf1 = arc.ARCMF(iv, arc.Schedule(key, iv, 1));
arc.PrintArray(mf1, "Main Function Iteration 1 Results");
c.WriteLine(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(mf0, mf1) ? "MF Gen success." : "MF Gen fail.");
```

```
internal byte[] ARCMF(in byte[] state, in byte[][] keys)
        {
            var output = state;
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                ARCLT.Permutate(ref output, ARCLT.MBLTv1, i);
                ARCBMGR(ref output);
                ARCLT.Permutate(ref output, ARCLT.SBLTv1, i);
                output = OTPArray(output, keys[i]);
            }
            return output; 
        }
```

The modification of IV happens specifically after `ARCLT.Permutate(ref output, ARCLT.MBLTv1, i);`

To help show this, heres some screenshots.

[Before ( I cant embed images :( )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3rTh.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wNC.png).

[And the function itself looks like this:](https://github.com/Naquino14/ARC-128/blob/6ac1656716fdc90b19e7507c7a030010c977770d/ARC-128/ARCLT.cs#L73)

```
internal static void Permutate(ref byte[] io, in byte[] table, int seed =  1)
        {
            seed = (seed == 0) ? 1 : seed;
            for (int i = 0; i <= io.Length - 1; i++)
                io[i] = (byte)((io[i] * seed % 256) ^ table[i]);
        }
```

And for those curious, heres what the program outputs:

```
Main Function Iteration 0 Results: 785B62AFE54AB7FA7A4EE63D67A311A8
Main Function Iteration 1 Results: F47B4EF85524B92B6F210F9EDCD5786
MF Gen fail.
```

What should I do?

Update 1: Changing the Permutate function to

```
internal static byte[] Permutate(byte[] io, in byte[] table, int seed =  1)
        {
            var o = io;
            seed = (seed == 0) ? 1 : seed;
            for (int i = 0; i <= io.Length - 1; i++)
                o[i] = (byte)((o[i] * seed % 256) ^ table[i]);
            return o;
        }
```

makes no difference.

Comment: I don't see anything `readonly` (which unlikely to change anything in the question anyway)... I'm pretty sure your expectations of what "method may not assign a value or modify the argument" means are unrealistic. Could you please [edit] the question to show [MRE] of code that you believe should not work? I think you  wanted `void X(in byte[] v){v[0]=42;}` as example of code that must not work.

Comment: parameter modifiers don't protect against interior mutability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing it in with Ref keywords. Ref will modify those values.

Make a copy of it and use the copy.

```
var output = new byte[state.Length];
state.CopyTo(output, 0);

or 

var output = state.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, although I am a bit confused on why... Is is because setting `output` to `state` copies over the reference?

Comment: It's because of **new** it creates a new object refenced by variable "output" in the memory heap and any changes are done to this new object the old object referenced by the variable "state" remains unchanged. Your earlier code was not working as expected because both the variables in the calling function as well as the "Permutate" function were still referencing the same object in memory. Recommended reading https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html and the links within that

Comment: Wilco, that makes sense. Ill be sure to read that article.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the `ref` keyword.
It allows sub-methods to modify the parameter's value in memory.
In your case, the parameter `output` (byte-structure typed) is modified twice when you set the value each time with:

`io[i] = (byte)((io[i] * seed % 256) ^ table[i]);`.

Comment: Changing the function to 
`internal static byte[] Permutate(byte[] io, in byte[] table, int seed =  1)
        {
            var o = io;
            seed = (seed == 0) ? 1 : seed;
            for (int i = 0; i <= io.Length - 1; i++)
                o[i] = (byte)((o[i] * seed % 256) ^ table[i]);
            return o;
        }`
doesnt help.